# Sharing Clipboard between non-networked PC's (KVM style)

Tags: network-shares, clipboard, kvm-switch

My situation is this: I have a PC which is joined to a domain, and another computer 'outside' that network.  I'd like to use a KVM style device to switch between them, but sharing the clipboard would be fantastic.  When searching for such a thing I found various patents for this type of thing (eg **http://www.freepatentsonline.com/6901455.html**) but can't see one actually for sale anywhere!

Anyone know of one?  Or an alternative suggestion - eg a program that uses USB or another method to connect two PC's and share clipboard without ethernet?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I see that this an older post/question that never seemed to get answered. While searching for something similar I came across this site <'https://awesomeopensource.com/project/Erriez/Clipboarder'> that may help you in your situation if it's still a need.

Cheers!